# How Selenium Webdriver checks for visibility of elements?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I was looking at this: ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated and thinking how robust is its implementation; are there any false positives or false negatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium itself sends a command to the browser. The browser sends back a response. The two cases I've seen where the browser considers an element to be not displayed are where it's style is set to "display: none;" or it has been positioned outside of the viewport. 10,000 pixels right for example.

Each browser will be implementing this differently but over the last three years of using Selenium I have not seen a false positive/negative.

You can read the code for the Python implementation of "is_displayed" in this file: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py

Comment: I don't find this "positioned outside of the viewport" criterion very reliable. In some cases (with certain frameworks for web applications) I got a lot of false-positives.

Comment: I guess I don't consider a partually obscured element to be visible. But yes. Good point.